# Can I import 2 files into each other?

Tags: python

Can I import File1 to File2 and File2 to File1? I get worried because of my knowledge of PHP's *include* statement and the recursive problems that introduces. If I can do that, would that be the best way to use a variable found in File1, in File2?

One way around would be adding another argument to doSomething that just passes numberX, but I don't feel creating another argument is the proper way to handle this.

**File1 (central file):**

```
import File2
class FooBar(): #a big object representing a wxFrame (GUI)
    doSomething()

class BarFoo(): #a big object representing a wxFrame (GUI)
    numberX = 12345

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance1 = FooBar()
    instance2 = BarFoo()
```

**File2 (helper functions):**

```
#from File1 import BarFoo?
def doSomething():
    #need numberX here somehow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with two modules (files) importing each other, although it is a technique that should generally only be used when required.

Just ensure that any references from the first module to second module don't rely on the first module (like if numberX was based off of the contents of File2). Intricate codependence like that doesn't exist in your code so you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can, but it's recommended. I said sometimes you can, because python knows a module is already imported and will not try to import it again, so python can handle circular module dependency at this point, but it does not mean every thing is right.

I'll show you a case where circular dependency causes problems.

There is a  `a.py` and it contains:

```
import b
def foo():
    return b.x
print "In module a: " + foo()
```

In `b.py`:

```
import a
x = '1'
def foo2():
    print "In module b: " + a.foo()
```

Then in a python command line, if you import `a.py`, it works fine:

```
>>> import a
In module a: 1
>>> import b
>>> b.foo2()
In module b: 1
```

But instead, if you import `b.py` first, it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
  File "a.py", line 4, in <module>
    print "In module a: " + foo()
  File "a.py", line 3, in foo
    return b.x
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'
```